# Сравнение массива и переменной в php

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Доброго времени суток!
 Есть задача:

1. Имеется многомерный массив;
2. Имеется пакет update передаваемый в переменную;
3. Необходимо сравнить значение переменной и массива (допустим in_array);
4. ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ (Тут проблема) какое значение из массива совпало с переменой;
5. Передать его (совпавшее значение в переменную;

Подскажите плиз функцию которая способна решить подобную задачу, т.к через key не получается

Comment: можешь написать input того что имеется и что нужно получить в итоге в виде переменных? А то  в виде слов немного размыто получается............. `через key не получается` - что именно не получается?  в чем это выражается? можешь показать что и как ты делаешь?

Comment: напишите конкретный вопрос получите конкретный ответ, а так могу только посоветовать копать в сторону array_walk_recursive.